# How to add multiple menu sections to toolbar?

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, android-menu

trying to create a toolbar programmatically and have run into a problem. I can add items fine, but the problem is that they all go under the same far right "more" section. No matter if I change the group id or the order every item falls under that same section. All help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the code to add the items:

```
public void setupToolbar(Toolbar t) {
        Menu editMenu = t.getMenu();
        t.setTitle(title);
        editMenu.add(20, 35, 200, "Title 2");
        editMenu.add(30, 45, 300, "Boom");
        editMenu.add(20, 55, 200, "Boom 2");
        editMenu.addSubMenu(10, 25, 100, "Title");
        t.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
    }
```

Here is the result of that:

[image]

Comment: you need to add elements to sub menu ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [`showAsAction`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setShowAsAction(int)) attribute on your `MenuItem`.

The one you are looking for ist probably `always` and / or `ifRoom`. Just set the correct value on the from `add` returned `MenuItem`.

Comment: Oh! That makes so much sense! Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I have these items setup now, but now I can not figure out how to add an extra menu to those actions.

Comment: you probably are looking for submenus to menuitems? but please open a new questions if you encounter specific problems as comments are not the place for Q&A